# Animate MatrixAnimationUsingPath not running on runtime in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have arrowhead and lines which working from my other [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68443557/3436326) for a prototype/proof of concept. Now, I want to apply to real application that contains more than 5 lines using the same arrowhead. So, I want to convert the matrix from code and start the storyboard on button click. Unfortunately, the animation is not starting(**the arrow is in first position and not moving through path data**)

I have follow sample from [MSFT Path Animations Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/graphics-multimedia/path-animations-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8).

Below are my current application

XAML:

```
<Path
    x:Name="Path_Room1"
    Width="68.729"
    Height="71.077"
    Data="M248.37977,129.8855 C248.37977,129.8855 248.37977,102.93943 248.37977,97.931796 248.37977,92.924162 253.51313,93.863426 263.68489,93.863426 273.85665,93.863426 274.63926,94.685097 274.63926,86.939011 274.63926,76.767263 274.63926,65.520282 274.63926,62.46878 274.63926,59.417279 277.53466,59.827827 280.50799,59.827827 283.48133,59.827827 316.10902,59.827827 316.10902,59.827827"
    Stretch="Fill"
    Stroke="Black" />
<Path
    x:Name="Arrowhead"
    Width="23"
    Height="19.5"
    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
    VerticalAlignment="Top"
    Data="M94,29 L117,39 95,49 99,38 z"
    Fill="#ff387cc0"
    Stretch="Fill">
    <Path.RenderTransform>
        <MatrixTransform />
    </Path.RenderTransform>
</Path>
```

Code-behind:

```
private void BtnRoom1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var pathdata = Path_Room1.Data;
    // I have to comment this as other animation is failed to found settargetname
    //NameScope.SetNameScope(this, new NameScope());
    PathGeometry animationPath = PathGeometry.CreateFromGeometry(pathdata);
    animationPath.Freeze();
    System.Windows.Media.Animation.MatrixAnimationUsingPath matrixAnimationUsingPath = new System.Windows.Media.Animation.MatrixAnimationUsingPath();
    matrixAnimationUsingPath.PathGeometry = animationPath;
    matrixAnimationUsingPath.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
    matrixAnimationUsingPath.RepeatBehavior = System.Windows.Media.Animation.RepeatBehavior.Forever;
    matrixAnimationUsingPath.DoesRotateWithTangent = true;

    System.Windows.Media.Animation.Storyboard.SetTarget(matrixAnimationUsingPath, Arrowhead);
    System.Windows.Media.Animation.Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(matrixAnimationUsingPath, new PropertyPath("RenderTransform.Matrix"));

    System.Windows.Media.Animation.Storyboard pathAnimationStoryboard = new System.Windows.Media.Animation.Storyboard();
    pathAnimationStoryboard.Children.Add(matrixAnimationUsingPath);

    Arrowhead.Loaded += delegate (object ss, RoutedEventArgs es)
    {
        pathAnimationStoryboard.Begin(this);
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attaching a handler to the `Loaded` event of the `Arrowhead` element has no effect if it is already loaded.

Besides that, you don't need a Storyboard in code behind.

```
private void BtnRoom1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var pathdata = Path_Room1.Data;
    var animationPath = PathGeometry.CreateFromGeometry(pathdata);
    animationPath.Freeze();

    var matrixAnimationUsingPath = new MatrixAnimationUsingPath
    {
        PathGeometry = animationPath,
        Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5),
        RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever,
        DoesRotateWithTangent = true
    };

    Arrowhead.RenderTransform.BeginAnimation(
        MatrixTransform.MatrixProperty,
        matrixAnimationUsingPath);
}
```